# Is Unit of Work pattern about sharing the same DataContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net, unit-of-work

I am using Entity Framework and I am trying to learn Unit of Work pattern in combination with Repository pattern.

From what i understood until now, Unit of Work is responsible with keeping track of the changes made to the entity objects. However, isn't the DataContext doing the same thing?

So, implementing unit of work pattern isn't like "forcing" you to use the same context across all methods?

```
public class EFUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    EFContext context = new EFContext();
    public void Commit()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class ProductsRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    /* CRUD methods here */
}

public void InsertProducts()
{
    var unitOfWork = new EFUnitOfWork(); // <-- this will normally be injected via constructor
    var productsRepository = new ProductsRepository(unitOfWork);

    productsRepository.Insert(new Product { Name = "Product 1", Description = "Description" });
    productsRepository.Insert(new Product { Name = "Product 2", Description = "Description" });
    productsRepository.Insert(new Product { Name = "Product 3", Description = "Description" });

    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Is this the right way of using Unit of Work with Entity Framework?

Comment: Pretty much. EF is an implementation of repository and UoW patterns with extra sprinkles.

Comment: DbContext is actually implemented following Unit Of Work, you don't need to wrap it.

Comment: @CuongLe That was my first thought, but why they are so many examples out there using EF with Unit of Work?

Comment: @RaraituL: Just ignore it, you need to understand UoW work, all ORM actually implement UoW for you, like dbContext or Session from NHibernate. What you need to do is to use it.

Comment: You need to implement UoW yourself, when your operation spans across multiple contexts (e.g. an EfDbContext and a Queue). Multiple records in the same DbContext is already handled as UoW out of the box by EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you share the same DataContext.  Here's a tutorial that will help you:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Ok, this is good. Just one more question: how do i make it to be independent of Entity Framework?

Comment: The pattern will work independent of EF.  I guess you can build your own data context class or use something else (Linq to Sql, NHibernate, etc.).